# How to highlight and collect highlighted text from webpages in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, software-rec

Is there a way to highlight lines of text in a Chrome webpage in various colours with a keyboard only or with a mouse only?  I want to highlight lines of text and I want the highlights to show up every time I visit the same site. Also, I want a backup feature so I never lose highlights.  And, I want to be able to press a button in the app that will download all the highlighted text bits to a document.

Freeware or paidware.  Stability of the product is important (losing hours of highlights is nuts).  Need it to be efficient too.

Chrome.

Comment: Not sure it offers everything you want, but I suggest you check out [Diigo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oojbgadfejifecebmdnhhkbhdjaphole/details) extension for Google Chrome.

Comment: Nice thing to have...

Answer (score 2):

These are currently your best options:

- [Diigo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oojbgadfejifecebmdnhhkbhdjaphole/details)
- [Yawas - Web Highlighter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kjlghdmljfgngjdpeaiogebkiilpiimk)
- [Super Simple Highlighter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-simple-highlighter/hhlhjgianpocpoppaiihmlpgcoehlhio)

All of them allow you to highlight text and even save notes.

Keep in mind that when the text on the webpage changes, your highlights will not show up anymore and might be lost. Diigo also offers to safe a cached version of the page as a backup just in case the website is changed or removed. But you will have to purchase a paid plan if you do not want to be severely limited. Here is a good comparison of their plans: http://www.diigo.com/premium/pricing_table_details

Also check out [Scrapbook](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fihabipakbgncingdhhdidlbhneeicne).
This extension saves an offline copy of the page and allows to highlight text. However these highlights will only show up in your ScrapBook collection and will not be highlighted on the live webpage.

There is also a comparable add-on for Firefox called [ScrapBook Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook-plus) which is more advanced.

Comment: But do any of these products have a feature to cut and paste all the highlights into say, Word?

Comment: If you use Diigo, it will show a list of all your highlights, sorted by most recent highlight. You can also search/sort/limit by tags.

Answer (score 0):

Check extension available at https://hypothes.is/ it allows you to create an account.